# Есть ли функция вывода дробных чисел в окно MessageBox?

Tags: строки, ассемблер, masm32

Я только начал изучать masm32, и столкнулся с проблемой того, что функция wsprintf() c WinApi32 не работает для дробных чисел.

```
.386
.model  flat,stdcall
option  casemap:none

include \masm32\include\windows.inc
include \masm32\include\user32.inc
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
includelib  \masm32\lib\user32.lib
includelib  \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib

.data
int_one DD  100
int_two DD  150.6

str_format  DB  "int_one = %d , int_two = %d",0
str_buffer  DB  256 dup (0)
mb_title    db  "Title Text Message",0

.code
start:
    invoke  wsprintf,ADDR str_buffer, ADDR str_format, int_one, int_two
    invoke  MessageBox,0,ADDR str_buffer, ADDR mb_title,MB_OK
    invoke  ExitProcess,0
end start
```

[image: Результат работы программы]

Существует ли функция которая возвращает заполненную форматированную строку с целыми и дробными числами, и с возможностю менять систему счисления между десятичной, двоичной и шестнадцатеричной. Буду искренне благодарен за ответ!

Comment: Как вариант, можно использовать функцию sprintf из msvcrt.dll - она поддерживает форматирование чисел с плавающей точкой.

Answer (score 0):

Дробные числа выводятся с помощью `%f`, надо переделать строку форматирования на

```
str_format  DB  "int_one = %d , int_two = %f",0
```